# Is it safe to change notification names between App updates?

Tags: ios, swift

My current notification names for `NSNotificationCenter` are constants, defined in a globally accessible singleton:

```
let notificationLeafletImageLongPressed = "com.mycompany.notificationLeafletImageLongPressed"
let notificationLeafletPageChanged = "com.mycompany.notificationLeafletPageChanged"
```

What I want to do is change it to something like this:

```
enum NotificationKey: String {
    case LeafletImageLongPressed
    case LeafletPageChanged
}
// Access
print(NotificationKey.LeafletImageLongPressed.rawValue)
```

In this way I have the compiler check that all names are really distinct.

I have now three questions:

1) As far as I understand updating an App on the device over the App Store always leads to terminating (and therefore to a re-start) of the App. Right?

2) Therefore it should be save to change notification names for `NSNotificationCenter` between updates. Right?

3) Currently the names are defined in reverse dns style (`com.mycompany.notificationName`) but afterwards they will just be `notificationName`. If this generally ok to do? Or should it be always reverse dns style? (then I can't change it to enums)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes, after an update, the app restarts.

2) Yes, it will save change to notification name because the change is in code and not in some persistent container (Keychain, UserDefaults etc).

3) *'notificationName'* looks much better than *'com.mycompany.notificationName'*. Although Apple recommends much more verbose names in their coding guidelines.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html

> Notifications are identified by global NSString objects whose names
>   are composed in this way:
>
> [Name of associated class] + [Did | Will] + [UniquePartOfName] +
>   Notification For example:
>
> NSApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
>   NSWindowDidMiniaturizeNotification
>   NSTextViewDidChangeSelectionNotification
>   NSColorPanelColorDidChangeNotification

Comment: Thanks vikram. I just found out that the reverse dns style is recommended for NSDistributedNotificationCenter.